# Changing a array type in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to change an array type inside my collection on MongoDB.

```
title: ['1', '2', '3']
```

to: `[1,2,3]`

I already changed at the model to:

```
title: [{
    type: Number,
}],
```

Already tried:

```
Users.updateMany({ title: "1" }, { $set: { 'titulos.$': 1} }, { safe: true, upsert: true }, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Comment: @mickl
MongoDB 4.0.10   & Mongoose 5.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for a one-time operation and you're using MongoDB 4.0, the easiest way would be to take advantage of [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html), [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html) to replace existing `title` for every user and then run [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to replace exising MongoDB collection (make sure it's named `users` in your database):

```
await User.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            title: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$title",
                    in: { $toInt: "$$this" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $out: "users" }
])
```